# How can I assign a single variable to multiple items in a list?

Tags: bash

If I want to check for a single user I can do this.

```
echo "enter username"
read -p "" usr

if [[ $(curl -sS https://example.com) = "online" ]]; then
    echo "$usr is online"
else
    echo "$usr is offline"
fi
```

But instead of entering a username every time I would rather read from a list.

```
cat userlist.txt
user1
user2
user3
user4
```

But how do I do that and still assign the variable `$usr` to each item in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read each line from file and assign it to `$user` with a loop :

```
#!/bin/bash

while read usr; do
  if [[ $(curl -sS https://example.com) = "online" ]]; then
      echo "$usr is online"
  else
      echo "$usr is offline"
  fi
done < userlist.txt
```